# Convergence of a family of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that for $D>0, D\equiv 0,1 \pmod4$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $ \operatorname{Im}(z)>0$ and $k>1$ the sum

$$\sum_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z} \\ b^2-4ac=D}(az^2+bz+c)^{-k}$$ converges absolutely.

Comment: What does $D\equiv 0,1 \pmod4$ mean?

Comment: $D \equiv 0  \pmod 4$ or $D \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ sorry if that was cloudy

Comment: You might wanted to put $b^2-4ac$ in two places, one under the sum, the other after your attempted proof.

Comment: Oh yes thanks for noticing the typo

Comment: My answer had serious flaws. I will come back if I resolve all issues.

Comment: Hi, you said $k>1$, but now are you assuming $k$ is an even positive integer?

Comment: I am still trying to fix up my argument. My approach is still through quadratic forms, $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ action on the upper half plane.

Comment: Hi, It's still $k>1$. I don't know how I did that mistake. I edited it

Comment: For a better understanding, would you please tell me where the problem is from? and what do you need this for?

Comment: Maybe you could add your former answer again and point the error out, so that I can think about it, too.

Comment: I have been editing my former answer. After "we need a bound for ...", I was not able to find a good bound that ensures convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually rather straightforward. If $a=0$, then $b$ can take at most 2 values, none of them $0$, and we are left with the absolutely convergent sum $\sum_c |c+bi|^{-k}$. If $c=0$, we can run a similar argument. So it is enough to consider $a,b,c\ne 0$. In this case the roots $u,v$ of the corresponding quadratic polynomial $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ are real and lie at the distance $\sqrt D$ from $-\frac b{2a}$. Thus $|P(z)|=|a||z-u||z-v|$. This is never less than $|a||\Im z|^2$ and for $|b|>(6\sqrt D+4|\Re z|)|a|$ is not less than $|a||\frac b{4a}|^2\approx \frac{|b|^2}{|a|}$. Thus, $|P(z)|\gtrsim\max(|a|,\frac{|b|^2}{|a|})\ge |b|$ and we only need to consider $\sum_{a,b,c}|b|^{-k}$. However, for fixed $b$, the number of non-zero pairs $(a,c)$ with $0\ne b^2-D=4ac$ is at most the number of divisors of $b^2-D$, which grows slower than any positive power of $|b|$.

Comment: It is not clear why we can assume $|b|>(6\sqrt D+4|\Re z|)|a|$. Would you please explain this?

Comment: @i707107 If $|b|$ is less, we just use the lower bound of $|a|$, which is better than $|b|^2/|a|$ in that case.

Comment: This works great! Now, I think I actually made the problem unnecessarily difficult. Do you have any suggestion on the bound of orbit points $\gamma z$ in my last figure?

Comment: One small typo is $u, v$ are real and lie at the distance $\sqrt D /2a$ from $-b/2a$. But, it does not affect the validity of this argument.

Comment: @i707107 Indeed. The intended meaning was "at the distance *at most* $\sqrt D$", but my midnight English can get quite lame. And, alas, no, I do not see how to bound the number of orbit points by something that would allow one to complete the proof in your way, though I should confess that I did not think really hard about it.

Comment: Cannot edit the comment anymore, I meant $O(|b|^{-k+\epsilon})$ for the second case.

Comment: @Deavor Yes, we just choose $\varepsilon<k-1$.

Comment: @Deavor $\gtrsim$ means "greater than or equal to some positive constant times...". The constant in question may depend on $z$ and is exactly $|\Im z|^2$. The same applies to the second estimate: it is enough to have $|b|/2$ on the RHS in your inequalities.

Comment: After many months, I found that my approach was incorrect one. This is because the same $a, b,c$ can be obtained by infinitely many $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited on 2019 11/18**.

This is an incorrect approach. Given $a,b,c$, there are infinitely many $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. For a correct approach, see fedja's answer.

**Old answer**

This is an incomplete answer using the Theory of Quadratic Forms. The constants $C$ appearing in this solution may not be the same. We begin with

**Definition**

> Let $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ be a quadratic form with $a, b, c\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b^2-4ac=D$. We say that a quadratic form $a_1x_1^2+b_1x_1y_1+c_1y_1^2$ with $a_1,b_1,c_1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b_1^2-4a_1c_1=D$ is equivalent to $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ if there is $\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that 
>   $$
> a_1x_1^2+b_1x_1y_1+c_1y_1^2=a(px_1+qy_1)^2+b(px_1+qy_1)(rx_1+sy_1)+c(rx_1+sy_1)^2.
> $$

This can be written again with matrices
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & \frac{b_1}2\\ \frac{b_1}2 & c_1 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}p & r \\ q & s \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a & \frac{b}2\\ \frac{b}2 & c \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The next one is the reducing step.

**Lemma 1**

> Any integer quadratic form with discriminant $D$ is equivalent to $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ with $|b|\leq |a|\leq |c|$.

The proof is a repeated application of the matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**Corollary 1**
The number of equivalence classes of integer quadratic forms with discriminant $D$ is finite.

If $b^2-4ac=D$ and $|b|\leq |a|\leq |c|$, then $|D|\geq 4|ac|-|b^2| \geq 3|ac|$ gives only finitely many choices for $a$ and $c$, subsequently for $b$.

Then it suffices to prove the following for $A=\begin{bmatrix}a& b/2\\ b/2&c\end{bmatrix}$ with $b^2-4ac=D$ and $|b|\leq |a|\leq |c|$, as the sum can be written as a finite sum of the following kind.

> The sum is absolutely convergent for $k>1$:
>   $$\sum_{\gamma\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})} \frac1{\left(| \gamma z - \alpha | |\gamma z - \alpha'|\right)^k|rz+s|^{2k}}  \ \ \ (*)
> $$
>   where $\gamma z=\frac{pz+q}{rz+s}$, $\alpha=\frac{-b-\sqrt{D}}{2a}$, and $\alpha'=\frac{-b+\sqrt{D}}{2a}$.

Note that after the reduction, we have $ac<0$ and $|\alpha-\alpha'|>1$.

Let $\Delta_{\gamma}$ be the area of a triangle with vertices at $\alpha, \alpha',\gamma z$. Let $\theta_{\gamma}$ be the angle formed by the corner $\alpha, \gamma z, \alpha'$. Then $\Delta_{\gamma}=\frac12| \gamma z - \alpha | |\gamma z - \alpha'|\sin \theta_{\gamma}=\frac12 |\alpha-\alpha'|\Im(\gamma z)=\frac12|\alpha-\alpha'| \frac{\Im(z)}{|rz+s|^2}$.

Thus, it suffices to prove the convergence of 
$$
\sum_{\gamma\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})} (\sin \theta_{\gamma})^k
$$

Consider $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $H=\left\{\pm\begin{bmatrix} 1&2m_0m\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, m\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. Fix a fundamental domain $F_{\infty}$ for $H$ as $F_{\infty}=\{z| u-m_0 \le \Re z < u+m_0\}$ and $u=\frac{\alpha+\alpha'}2$. Here we set the integer $m_0$ large enough that  $u-m_0<\min(\alpha,\alpha')<\max(\alpha,\alpha')<u+m_0$.
For $\gamma z\notin F_{\infty}$, $\gamma z$ is sufficiently away from any of $\alpha$, $\alpha'$. Thus, we have
$$
\sum_{(r,s)=1, \  \begin{bmatrix} *&*\\r&s\end{bmatrix} z \notin F_{\infty}}\frac1{\left(| \gamma z - \alpha | |\gamma z - \alpha'|\right)^k|rz+s|^{2k}}\ll \sum_{(r,s)=1} \frac1{|rz+s|^{2k}}
$$
due to $\sum \frac 1{n^k}$ is convergent. Moreover, the sum on the right side is 
$$
\ll \sum_{(r,s)=1, \ rs\neq 0} \frac1{|rs|^k}
$$
which is also convergent. The implied constants depend on $k,\alpha,\alpha',m_0,z$.

Thus, we consider the following sum
$$
\sum_{\gamma\in H\backslash \Gamma} (\sin\theta_{\gamma})^k=\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma, \ \gamma z \in F_{\infty}} (\sin \theta_{\gamma})^k.
$$
We need a bound for the number of orbit points $\gamma z$ in the following figure. [image]

Comment: Since we can interpret quadratic forms as matrices:$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=ax^2+(b+c)xy+dy^2$$, we may have that decomposition. Please postpone accepting, because I found an error in Lemma 2 and need to fix it.